# Relation between nilpotent matrix and matrix with simple elementary divisors

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras, jordan-normal-form

I am studying the paper,
*Goto, Morikuni*, [**On algebraic Lie algebras**](https://doi.org/10.2969/jmsj/00110029), J. Math. Soc. Japan 1, 29-45 (1948). [ZBL0038.02104](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0038.02104).
Here the author proves the unique decomposition of a matrix into a nilpotent matrix and a $s$-matrix as $X=X^0+X^s$. By a $s$-matrix he means a matrix with simple elementary divisors. He remarks that the $s$-matrix is got by taking the diagonal part of Jordan canonical form of $X$. I am not able to get how the nilpotent part is obtained. Each Jordan block is expressed as $\lambda I+N$ where $N$ is nilpotent. But how do I arrive at a nilpotent matrix? How is that $X^0$ and $X^s$ commute?

Also in the next step, he states, $X^s$ can be written as $\xi_1X_1+\xi_2X_2\ldots \xi_kX_k$ uniquely where $\xi_i$'s are taken from a suitable Hamel basis. But any fixed basis for the base field $K$ would do the job? Why Hamel basis?

Comment: The nilpotent part is the nilpotent part of the Jordan canonical form just as the semisimple part is the semisimple (aka diagonalisable over the closure) part. You can in fact see that $X^0$ and $X^s$ are polynomial in $X$ so commute with anything that $X$ commutes with and in particular with each other. See Humphreys' *Intro to Lie Algebras* section 4.2.